# R: compilation failed for package ‘littler’

Tags: r, littler

When I running R in the container and trying to install a R package `littler`, there gives some errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzma
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makevars:29: recipe for target 'r' failed
make: *** [r] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘littler’
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system is missing a number of system development libraries for compiling littler.

You don't say what OS this is, but typically you'd use `apt` on Ubuntu/Debian and `yum` on CentOS to install packages like `libz-devel` which contains the files needed to compile software that works with `libz`, the compression library, and similarly for `libpcre` the regular expression library, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's CentOS. However I'm not a root user. I've tried to export the path to bashrc, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you ask your sysadmin to install all the dependencies needed? Otherwise you may have to compile *everything* from source code.